who declared Gautama Buddha 9th incarnation of Vishnu
In some temples, Gautam Buddha is depicted as the 9th avatar of Vishnu. Despite researching various sources, I couldn't find a definitive reference for this. While some temples regard Balarama as the 9th avatar, others suggest that Buddhism's significant influence on Indian society at one time led to an attempt to integrate Buddhism with Hinduism.
can someone give a insight on this

Many Puranas say so.

Agni Purana -


"I am describing the manifestation (of Visnu) as Buddha, by reading and hearing which one gets wealth. Once in the battle between devas
and asuras, devas were defeated by the daityas (demons, sons of Diti).
They sought refuge in the lord saying, “Protect us! Protect us!”. He
(Visnu), who is of the form of illusory delusion became the son of
Śuddhodana. He deluded those demons. Those, who had abandoned the
path laid down in the Vedas, became the Bauddhas and from them others
who had abandoned the Vedas."


Chapter 16, Agni Purana.


yes Budha is mentioned in multiple hindu texts like bhagvat puran,Vushnu puran,Garud puran Agni puran.. These purans indicate to certain extent that Budha is incarnation of Vishnu who has abandoned vedic scructure and will spread the concept of Ahinsa, But Puranas were composed way late when budhism already had much influence in society.
